# EF Table per Hierarchy (TPH) not saving because can't insert value null in Discriminator column

Tags: entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I have a table used for multiply type of category and it contains a Discriminator column named 'ClassName' to specify the type of object to load. The ClassName column is non nullable with a default value of 'Category'

My problem is when saving a new item , I get the error : 
'Cannot insert the value null into column ClassName' table Category.

I tought that ef would set the ClassName value base on the new object class.
How can I save my object with the right 'ClassName' value ?

Comment: Yes, EF should care about the `Discriminator` column values in TPH mapping. I think you must show your code because something is likely not correct in your entities or mappings. Do you have for example configured that the discriminator column name is `ClassName` (which is not default)?

Comment: I use the UI to set my discriminator in the edmx, Right click the table, select table mapping, In Maps to Category i set  when ClassName = CategoryRoot it works fine and create my CategoryRoot object, but from my category when i add a new category the classname value is set to null, i want is set to Category. I will lookup how to set the discriminator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my db Structure to accept null. EF will set null if the object name match the table name and will set the discreminator name for the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but I just met it today. In .net 4.0 code first I don't meet "disclaimer column" but when downgrade to net 3.5, it make me tired for a day.
This is my solution

Change the column in the database to ALLOW NULL (using alter table)
and update the edmx file to make it update the change(allow null)